# Capacitive Sensor and Thread

Tags: sensors, threads

Looking for a great way to detect when someone touches thread, or if 4 people touch thread etc.

I'm not looking for a hand count, but I'm going to try to translate it into MIDI for use in a project.

Am I looking for a form of capacitive sensor?

Comment: what kind of thread?

Comment: something like this: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/50m-Orange-Builders-Line-PACK-OF-2-Rope-String-Building-Brick-Masonry-Home-DIY-/311438519959

Comment: No, unless you use wire.  Or, maybe, conductive thread.  Mentioning MIDI implies you want to make music.  Indicate if this is so - as I'm thinking there are much more reliable alternative that you could use.

Comment: The Arduino Lilypad boards might be the right place to start https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/sewing-with-conductive-thread

Comment: I have conductive thread, but it might be a case of finding a nicer looking thread with conductivity, this thread is very thin, not appealing to touch at all